# Update de dados com IONIC e Firebase

Tags: ionic, firebase

Boa noite, estou estudando Firebase com IONIC e Angular(não estou usando o AngularFire) e surgiu uma dúvida.
Como faço para atualizar os dados salvos no  Firebase?
Para pegar os dados faço da seguinte forma:

```
const config = {
    apiKey: "x",
    authDomain: "x",
    databaseURL: "x",
    projectId: "x",
    storageBucket: "x",
    messagingSenderId: "x"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  let ref = firebase.database().ref('statuspedido');//statuspedido

  this.pedidos = new Array();

  ref.on('value', (dataSnapshot) =>{
     let items = dataSnapshot.val();
     for(let dados in items){
        this.pedidos.push(
            new PedidoModel(
                items[dados].dataEmissao, 
                items[dados].dataAtualizacao, 
                items[dados].vendedor, items[dados].frete, 
                items[dados].transportadora, items[dados].status)
        )
     }
  })
```

Minha estrutura no firebase está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quero por exemplo fazer o update do "idPedido = 1" sem alterar os demais.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar o método `update`, que você encontra na [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=pt-br):

```js
var objeto = {
      a : 'a',
      b : 'b'
    };
    
    firebase.database().ref('caminho/para/o/meu/objeto').update(objeto)
    .then(function (retorno){
            //se cair aqui, os dados foram atualizados com sucesso
         })
    .catch(function (error){
            //se cair aqui, deu erro
     });
```

Você também pode atualizar dois lugares ao mesmo tempo:

```js
var objeto = { a : 'teste' };
var atualizacoes = {};      
atualizacoes['usuario/'] = objeto;
atualizacoes['todos/']=objeto;
      
      
firebase.database().ref('caminho/para/o/meu/objeto').update(atualizacoes)
   .then(function (retorno){
          //se cair aqui, os dados foram atualizados com sucesso
       })
   .catch(function (error){
          //se cair aqui, deu erro
   });
```

Comment: Bom dia, fiz como me passou porém ao invés de atualizar ele cria novos objeto. Preciso atualizar um objeto específico.

Comment: ```.update``` vai atualizar o objeto se ele já existir, senão, ele cria um novo